# get_query_var return false

Tags: url-rewriting

I created a custom endpoint with add_rewrite_endpoint

```
function wp_en_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint('en', EP_ALL);
}
add_action('init', 'wp_en_endpoint' );
```

But when I use get_query_var( 'en' ), it returns an empty string

http://localhost/wordpress/shop/en/some-value/

Please tell me if I made a mistake !!

Comment: Have you flushed permalinks? Visiting _Settings > Permalinks_ should be sufficient.

Comment: yes, I did this